# SQL, Converting date timestamp variable into strings 'yyyymmdd' and 'yyyymm'

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, impala, hue

I would like to replace a date timestamp variable 'date' with the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss e.g, 2021-12-28 00:00:00
with two other string variables; one named date with the format: 'yyyymmdd' e.g, 20211228, and one named month with the format: 'yyyymm' e.g, 202112.

Can you give me some suggestions using a SELECT statement?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just use TO_CHAR (or whatever the equivalent is for your DBMS) and the appropriate format string

Comment: Could you please elaborate? i am using SELECT to_char(`date`, 'HH12:MI:SS')
from table1, and I am getting the error AnalysisException: database1.to_char() unknown

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: Hue-Impala SQL!

Comment: You need to use CAST : https://docs.cloudera.com/cdp-private-cloud-base/7.1.6/impala-sql-reference/topics/impala-conversion-functions.html?q=to_char